# How to change width of Featured /Latest module extension in open cart?

Tags: css, opencart

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this. i want to change width of my both the latest/ Featured module so that all products comes under same width as slide show nice and centre not in left as can be seen from the website http://www.ehfurnishing.co.uk. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the image below.

Comment: Please, do not post the same question more than once. If You had no answers that's probably because the question lacks some important information or is not kind of question that should be asked on StackOverflow. If You think You need to add some more details or change something, feel free to edit Your own (first) question instead of creating a new one asking for the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case  and depending in yout question you just need to add:

```
.box {
width: 980px;
}
```

in the end of your **stylesheet.css** in this directory

'catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet'

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, it did help i must say and it did change the width to exact same as slideshow, however it did messed up my categories pages so for instance when i go on page such as wardrobe as you can see from website it has changed the width of all the columns including product. Please help me on this as to how can i just specify this code only on featured/latest modules not rest of website. Thanks any response on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want it to be specific then you have to change that rule to   .extra_box{
width: 980px;
}  also you need to set those classes in featured.tpl and latest.tpl, and change the line <div class="box"> to div <class="box extra_box">

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this has solved the problem for now. Didn't have to set that in classes just had to change line to <div class="box extra_box"> in both featured and latest.tpl i tried putting div outside as you mentioned but didn't work had to put it inside brackets. Thanks once again :)

Comment: i am sorry but i wrote it quickly and did not notice that i wrote it like that, although it is common syntax :), glad i could help you, also i should advise to use debugging in chrome for css and other relative error, will greatly help you to achieve other things that you may need. Try inspect code in google chrome, and you can change css code directly so you can notice the differences.